# How can I create a textClip with multiple texts in moviepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

How can I create a TextClip with multiple texts
for example a text shows near the top and another at bottom at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

There's a few solutions depending on what effect you're looking for.

**tip*: Print screenshots to save time debugging:

```
video_clip.save_frame("frame.png", t=3) #where t=time_to_screenshot
```

**Option 1:** Use `\n` to break lines; then use parameter `interline` to manipulate the number of pixels between lines.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

txt ="Line 1\nLine2"
text_clip = mp.TextClip(txt,font='Ariel',interline=200,fontsize=54).set_duration(3)
text_clip.save_frame(f"screenshot.png")
```

**tip:* use `myVideo.size` to get a tuple (width,height) of a video object to use while positioning text clips

**Option 2:** Create two separate TextClips and add them to the top & bottom of another video.

```
text_clip0 = mp.TextClip("Line1",font='Ariel', fontsize=54)
text_clip1 = mp.TextClip("Line2",font='Ariel', fontsize=54)
background = mp.ColorClip(size=(720, 720), color=[255,255,255]).set_duration(6)
bgSize = background.size
tc1Size = text_clip1.size
final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([background,text_clip0.set_position("top"), text_clip1.set_position((bgSize[0]/2-tc1Size[0]/2, bgSize[1]-tc1Size[1]))])
#replicates text_clip1.set_position("bottom")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple TextClips and merge them into a [CompositeVideoClip](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html?highlight=textclip#compositevideoclip) by doing something like

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

text_1 = mp.TextClip("text1", color='white', align='West', fontsize=40, font='Arial', method='label').set_position(("center", "top"))
text_2 = mp.TextClip("text2", color='white', align='West', fontsize=40, font='Arial', method='label').set_position(("center", "bottom"))
full_text = mp.CompositeVideoClip([text_1, text_2])
```

Comment: The set_position doesn't work any solution on this @Tristo

Comment: You were almost correct. The CompositeVideoClip doesn't have a height so its the same height as the textclips which makes top/bottom useless.
Try:
full_text = mp.CompositeVideoClip([text_1, text_2], size=[1000, 2000])

Comment: Tried setting the size, and unfortunately it doesn't work for me @Nexarius. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use SubtitlesClip with TextClip for adjust fontsize, color, bg_color and more

> create function can optimize and reduce this code

```py
generator1 = lambda txt : TextClip(txt, font='wqy-microhei.ttc', fontsize=190, color='white')
subs1 = [((1, 4), '多い')]

generator2 = lambda txt : TextClip(txt, font='wqy-microhei.ttc', fontsize=140, color='white')
subs2 = [((1, 4), 'おおい\nooi')]

subtitles1 = SubtitlesClip(subs1, generator1)
subtitles2 = SubtitlesClip(subs2, generator2)

video = VideoFileClip('./background.mp4').subclip(0,5)
result = CompositeVideoClip([video, subtitles1.set_position(('center', 500)), subtitles2.set_position(('center', 700))])
result.write_videofile('out.mp4', fps=video.fps, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).